# C++ no appropriate default constructor available - inherited templated constructor w/ no arguments

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I've looked at over a dozen qst's with the phrase `no appropriate default constructor available` in it but none help with my own problem.

It's a very basic C++ qst (as I'm still learning the ropes), so sorry in advance if your eyes are glazing over at it's simplicity. I am trying to inherit a class that has a templated constructor with no arguments.  Such as:

```
class Base {
public:

template<class T>
Base() {
  T *t = this;
  //more irrelevant stuff
}

}
```

I've tried

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived() : Base() {

  }
}
```

and

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived() {

  }
}
```

to no avail.  In both cases I get the error message `no appropriate default constructor available` .  How to go about doing this?  If this is not possible can you explain why?

It worked when I set up my constructor like `template<class T> Base(T *t)` (taking the template argument as a parameter).

p.s.  In case it matters, in my code I am also inheriting `Derived` by another class.

Comment: Why do you need `T`? Can't you just do `Base* t = this;`?

Comment: I haven't tried, but you might need `Derived() : Base<Type>()`. I think CRTP might work better here.

Comment: @sftrabbit  From what I observe, when a base class is inherited the `this` pointer then points to the top-most inheriting class.

Comment: To downvoters:  Admittedly this is a basic qst, but it's within the scope of stackoverflow.  If you care to explain why this deserves a downvote then I could avoid making such mistakes in the future. Thanks.

Comment: None of the suggestions so far have worked.  No one knows?

Comment: @BobBlogge: how about you refresh your page in the browser, like?

Comment: @chris The CRTP appears to be the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no syntax for accessing the default constructor in

```
class blah_t
{
public:
    template< class other_t > blah_t() {}
};
```

there also some other ways to make the default constructor inaccessible, e.g.

```
class blah_t
{
public:
    blah_t() {}
    blah_t( int = 666 ) {}
};
```

as the holy standard explains it, constructors don't have names…

but, back to the original question, in order to be able to specify the template argument, you need some *ordinary function argument* that involves the template parameter type

Comment: I see.  So the only way to get it to work would be to include `(T *t)` or something?  Constructor arguments.

Comment: I changed it to 'template<class T> Base(T *t)` then pass in `this` as the constructor argument.  It achieves the same effect as what I was trying to do but I get the compiler warning `'this' : used in base member initializer list`.  Why the warning for passing in 'this` as the constructor argument?

Comment: some compilers warn about it because in the most general case it's *possible* to do ungood things, like referencing something that's not yet initialized. if you can, just turn off that warning. for good work it's best to have completely clean compiles, no diagnostics, so that you are sure to take note of any real diagnostic. that said, what you're doing with this templating sounds a bit odd. but you'd have to post more complete code or description in order for readers to be able to suggest alternatives.

Comment: Cheers - After consideration I think you are right to say it's an odd way to use templating.  My primary goal is to stick to standard C++ as I want to develop a class that can be reused by others.  The CRTP solution appears to be the way to go.